# Best practice - Dynamic control creation or separate pages?

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, webforms

I'm trying to decide on how best to implement an enhancement to a particular process in a C# ASP.NET 4.0 (just recently up from 3.5) web application. I'm looking for best practices and perhaps your own insight if you've implemented something similar in your development experience.

An overview of the particular process I'm working with:

- A user creates a request (called a request for modification) via an aspx form to update certain properties of a piece of equipment
- The type of modification the user chooses *and* some underlying info about the piece of equipment determines which properties of that piece of equipment can actually be changed.

There are 3 groups of properties that are ultimately changeable (a little simplified but pretty accurate):

1. Address information (i.e. where the equipment is - city, state, street address, etc)
2. Location coordinates (latitude, longitude)
3. Internal company accounting identifiers

Depending on the type of modification, elements in 1 - 3 may be open for editing, only those in #2, or only #3. When properties *cannot* be edited, I would like not to just have their values in disabled controls (and the form look the same for every type of modify request), but rather display the non-editable data in a nice visual format.

So as I began designing the solution, I started down the path of creating dynamic controls thinking something ilke this:

```
Page_Init()

switch (modificationType){
    case 1 : Create one set of controls
    case 2 : Create a different set of controls
    case 3 : Create another set
}
```

And then I thought to set the property values of the controls in `Page_Load()`.

Then I realized that the same type of conditional statement would need to be implemented there because (for example) the street address in one type of modification may need to be the value of a `TextBox` while for another it might be display-only and inside `Literal`.

It just seemed to start getting bloated fairly quickly and not very "dynamic-feeling" at all and I feel there is maybe something I'm missing just due to not enough experience. And I'm absolutely certain that creating 3 separate pages that essentially do the same thing with slight variations is wasteful and certainly not implementing good design practices. Input on the typical approach to something like this would be much appreciated.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you have 3 areas (1-3) that show data and each area has a read-only mode and an edit mode. So you have 6 "views" in total that could appear or not depending on the data the user has supplied. Is that accurate?

Comment: You are absolutely correct, yes. Thinking of the 3 sets as having edit and read-only modes had just started to dawn on me... but still not sure what the next step might be.

Comment: In that case, you could create 3 usercontrols that each one of them will have a read-only and an edit mode. The .aspx page can make each control load the propert mode based on the input. If need me to explain this a bit more, I could write a small example.

Comment: I completely see where you're going and I've written many UserControls for the app... in the form of re-usable drop-downs and the typical header/footer/side menu. If you wouldn't mind a small example of a UserControl that holds a couple of street address fields that would be great. Text boxes for edit mode and something simple like an <h3> tag for read-only. I think I know where this would head but would be very appreciative to see your suggestion. If you have time... in the meantime, I'm on it anyway being very intrigued.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create 3 usercontrols that each one of them will have a read-only and an edit mode. The .aspx page can make each control load the propert mode based on the input. I used markup classes from Bootstrap.

Lets assume a class that will contain the data the user control presents:

**Data**:

```
public class Address
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string street { get; set; }
    public string number { get; set; }
    public string city { get; set; }
    public string zipcode { get; set; }
    public string phone { get; set; }
}
```

The user control that uses this class is here:

**address.ascx** file

```
<asp:PlaceHolder ID="ReadModePlaceHolder" runat="server">
    <address>
        <strong>
            <asp:Literal ID="NameLiteral" runat="server"></asp:Literal></strong><br />
        <asp:Literal ID="StreetLiteral" runat="server"></asp:Literal><br />
        <asp:Literal ID="CityLiteral" runat="server"></asp:Literal><br />
        <abbr title="Phone">P:</abbr>
        <asp:Literal ID="PhoneLiteral" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
    </address>
</asp:PlaceHolder>
<asp:PlaceHolder ID="EditModePlaceHolder" runat="server">
    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="<%=NameTextBox.ClientID%>" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Name</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                <asp:TextBox ID="NameTextBox" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="<%=StreetTextBox.ClientID%>" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Street</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                <asp:TextBox ID="StreetTextBox" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="<%=NumberTextBox.ClientID%>" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Number</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                <asp:TextBox ID="NumberTextBox" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="<%=CityTextBox.ClientID%>" class="col-sm-2 control-label">City</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                <asp:TextBox ID="CityTextBox" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="<%=ZipCodeTextBox.ClientID%>" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Zip code</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                <asp:TextBox ID="ZipCodeTextBox" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="<%=PhoneTextBox.ClientID%>" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Phone</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                <asp:TextBox ID="PhoneTextBox" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                <asp:Button ID="SubmitButton" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-default" Text="Submit" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</asp:PlaceHolder>
```

**address.ascx.cs** file

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}

public void LoadReadMode(Address data)
{
    ReadModePlaceHolder.Visible = true;
    EditModePlaceHolder.Visible = false;

    NameLiteral.Text = data.name;
    StreetLiteral.Text = data.number + ", " + data.street;
    CityLiteral.Text = data.city + ", " + data.zipcode;
    PhoneLiteral.Text = data.phone;
}

public void LoadEditMode(Address data)
{
    ReadModePlaceHolder.Visible = false;
    EditModePlaceHolder.Visible = true;

    NameTextBox.Text = data.name;
    StreetTextBox.Text = data.street;
    NumberTextBox.Text = data.number;
    CityTextBox.Text = data.city;
    ZipCodeTextBox.Text = data.zipcode;
    PhoneTextBox.Text = data.phone;
}
```

In the .aspx page that has this user control you can call the `LoadReadMode(...)` or `LoadEditMode(...)` depending on the data you are having.

Comment: I really love this approach. Thank you so much for your help, Tasos! I'm going with it.